# How can I attach a listener to a variable inside my angularjs controller?

Tags: angularjs

I want to attach a listener to my  titleChanged variable. 
I've tried this way but it throws this error

TypeError: this.$watch is not a function

```
        var titleChanged = false;

        function titleTrue() {
            titleChanged = true;
        };
        $scope.$watch('title',function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                $timeout(titleTrue(), 5000)
            };
        });
        this.$watch('titleChanged', function(newValue){
            if(newValue === true) {
                    updateNote();
                    titleChanged = false;
                };
        });
```

the updated code another apprach

```
        var titleChanged = false;

        $scope.$watch('title',function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (newValue !== oldValue) {
                titleChanged = true;
            }
        });

        while (true) {
            $timeout(checkForChangeAndSave, 3000);
        };

        function checkForChangeAndSave() {
            if(titleChanged) {
                updateNote();
                titleChanged = false;
            }
        }


        function updateNote() {
            notesService.update($stateParams.id, {title: $scope.title});
            notesService.getAll();
        };
```

Comment: Watches changes in the variable on the $scope object. The framework is "watching" the variable. Watches are created using the $scope.$watch() function which I will cover later in this text.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is most likely referencing the controller object in your case *(unless you've manually bound to another value (or you've set up the `this.$watch` inside another function scope)).* It does not have a `$watch` method.

`$scope` has such a method however. If you want to look at the value of a local non-exposed variable you would do this:

```
$scope.$watch(function () { return titleChanged; }, function (v) {
  console.log(v);
});
```

Comment: I see. I tried the above but it didn't solve my problem. I then tried another approach using a while loop. But now the execution is stuck  inside the loop. I have updated the code